# How hard is it to convert the new(ish) RC/PF trains to 9V?

Tags: trains, compatibility, 9v

I have a HUGE investment in 9V trains (think many thousands of USD) and was wondering how difficult it is to convert the newer RC/PF train systems over to 9V motors? Do the 9V motors fit? Does the base have space for the trucks? Is it even worth it (keep in mind, I hate batteries)? Converting the 12V trains to 9V was rather easy.

I haven't ventured out to purchase a set yet (even though they've been out for a few years now -- I'm lazy and cheap I guess) because they're all rather expensive (as we know), so I have not been able to check myself.

Comment: When you say 9V train motors, what do you mean?  Are you talking about these motors:  http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=590  If so, then what do you mean by "convert RC/PF trains systems over to 9V motors"?  The PF train motors and the 9V motors are basically two completely separate and distinct parts the perform the same function.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about taking the new PF trains and making them run on those 9V motors and ditching the PF remote control thing and PF functions. I don't know the size of the PF motors, how they work, if the base of the train is sized appropriately for the 9v motor to fit, etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dense, but I see no reason why you can't just interchange them.  I feel like your question is something like "Can I convert a Stanley Phillips screwdriver to be a Black & Decker Phillips screwdriver?"  They are two *completely* separate things that both perform the same functions.  They fit on the same tracks (obviously the 9V trains need the 9V track, but the dimensions are the same) and they take up more-or-less the same brick space.  You might have to do some minimal rebuilding to make them fit, but it shouldn't be substantial.

Comment: I don't think you're being dense, but I don't think you're seeing my perspective... I've never even so much as seen a PF train in-person, so I have no idea how big the motors are. The question is mainly, will I completely have to redesign the motorized car, or  is the 9V motor a drop-in replacement, or something in between. It's not like the screwdriver thing you mention, it's more along the lines of are Stanley drill batteries compatible with Black & Decker drill batteries, or is there some modification necessary to use one with the other (in keeping with the tools metaphor). :-)

Comment: BTW, I don't know if I made this entirely clear: I only want 9V trains, I don't want any trains powered by batteries, but the new PF train models are quite nice and I would buy them except they run on batteries and so I would convert them to 9V motors if it's not a big deal to do so. If I have to completely redesign the motorized car, it's a lot less appealing.

Comment: Ahh, I understand.  It should be a fairly simple drop in.  Like I said, a little rebuilding might be needed, but not much.  If there is a particular set you are looking at, then you could get the instructions on BrickSet.  That would give you a good sense of compatibility with your 9V motors.  For reference, most PF trains use this motor: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=x1688a, which is nearly identical to the 9V one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PF train motor](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x1688a&in=S) has the same size and shape as the previous 9V Motors, and a lot of people are happily substituting one for the other.

The [Emerald Night](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10194-1), however, doesn't use that motor, so there your job will be much more tricky. Usually people change the tender to add two 9V motors there, but the wheel train of the engine tends to derail fairly easily if pushed that way (I strongly suggest you read [RailBricks issue #7](http://railbricks.com/magazine/issue-7/) for tips on how to make it run smoothly)